# Install / downgrade specific version of Node.js

Tags: apt, snap, nodejs

I have this:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs=11
```

but I get:

> E: Version '11' for 'nodejs' was not found

I also tried:

```
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs=11*
```

does anyone know how I can find out which versions are available? The **problem** is that node version 12 is already installed on this machine and I want to *downgrade* the Node.js version here.

Answer (score 2):

Because 12 is already installed, I had to do this:

```
# apt-get remove -y nodejs  # key part
# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
# apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

just drop that `=11` part. Like this:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

and

```
node -v
v11.15.0
```

The reason is that first `curl` command installs the repository which replaces `apt`'s pointer for nodejs - so no need to specify the version.

Comment: see my answer, I had to remove the previous version

Comment: This does not answer the question, as a specific version was requested.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

the only problem that I see is the "nodejs=11" in the apt-get, that should do it.

You can find the versions here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

The stable version is currently the 10.x

Comment: see my answer, I had to remove the previous version

Comment: Oh sorry, glad you managed to solve it!